# Offline charging usb port doesn't work in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, usb

My Sony Viao had a offline USB charging port to charge phones even when the system was off but since i have deleted windows 8 and installed ubuntu 14.04 i am not able to use this feature. Was the offline USB port feature of Windows is there anyway to get it up and running in ubuntu 14.04? 
Thank You.

Comment: I have the same port on my Lenovo, and it works fine.  Check BIOS settings, or maybe a BIOS update.

Comment: Possible: could it be windows 8 was hibernating when it works? (the vaio has a controle center in windows 8 that has an option to turn this on; that to me seems to make this a SOFTWARE method and not hardware). If so try hibernating Ubuntu and not shutting it down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This forum](http://www.techsupportforum.com/forums/f217/usb-power-during-sleep-639090.html) may help. It advises that you:

1. Look in the BIOS, as that is often the place it is controled and
2. Make sure that the device is plugged in before shutting down / putting to sleep.

Finally (and this is completely a workaound, you could buy one of these: [UK](http://www.amazon.co.uk/ADAPTOR-CHARGER-BLACKBERRY-SAMSUNG-UNIVERSAL/dp/B00CLQY8DQ/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1404818731&sr=8-1&keywords=usb%20charger%20plug) and [US](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00KIBAOKW)